# JSONMarshalled not working in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe7

I have the following simple class using Delphi XE7

```
{$M+}
{$RTTI EXPLICIT FIELDS([vcPrivate])}
TEntityForCreation = class
private
  [JSONMarshalled(False)]
  FCreator: Integer;
  FDescription: String;
public
  property Creator: Integer read FCreator write FCreator;
  property Description: String read FDescription write FDescription;
  function ToJsonString: string;
  class function FromJsonString(AJsonString: string): TEntityForCreation;
end;
```

The method ToJsonString uses the built in JSON serializing

```
function TEntityForCreation.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;
```

For some reason, the Creator element is always being serialized in the Json string. I have turned "Emit Run Time Type information" to True in the project options.

Stepping through the JSON marshalling code, I see it is just not recognizing that the JSONMarshalled is linked to FCreator. I figure I am missing some compiler directive somewhere, but cannot figure it out.

Comment: Try using REST.JSon.Types instead of DBXJSONReflect?

Comment: That was it. I did not have either REST.JSON.TYPES nor DBXJSONReflect in the uses clause and the program still compiled. So I did not think of that, and just assumed JSONMarshalled was in REST.JSON.. Thank you!!

Comment: You probably would have got a compiler warning if you didn't use either of those units.