# JSONMarshalled not working in Delphi XE10 (again)

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have a class I want to pass to a datasnap server, but the class contains this field Picture which should be a TPicture but for now I use an integer to avoid getting the marshall error "tkPointer currently not supported" :(

I have tried omitting a field/property "Picture" from getting marshalled by adding [JSONMarshalled(False)] but with no luck.

I have added the units as suggested in the thread here
[JSONMarshalled not working in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931434/jsonmarshalled-not-working-in-delphi)

```
unit TestObjU;

interface

uses
  Classes, System.Generics.Collections, System.SyncObjs, System.SysUtils,
  JSON, DBXJsonReflect, REST.JSON,
  Data.FireDACJSONReflect, FireDAC.Comp.Client, vcl.ExtCtrls,
  pngimage, graphics, variants,
  GlobalFunctionsU, GlobalTypesU;

{$M+}
{$RTTI EXPLICIT FIELDS([vcPrivate])}
type
  EPerson = class(Exception);
  EPersonsList = class(Exception);

  TGender = (Female, Male);

  TPerson = class(TObject)
  private
    FFirstName: string;
    FLastName: string;
    FId: Integer;
    FGender: TGender;
    FModified : Boolean;
    [JSONMarshalled(False)]
    FPicture: Integer;
//    [JSONMarshalled(False)] FPicture : TPicture;
    function GetName: string;
    procedure SetFirstName(const Value: string);
    procedure SetLastName(const Value: string);
    function GetId: Integer;
    procedure SetGender(const Value: TGender);
    procedure SetModified(const Value: Boolean);

  public
    property Id : Integer read GetId;
    property Name : string read GetName;
    property FirstName : string read FFirstName write SetFirstName;
    property LastName : string read FLastName write SetLastName;
    property Gender : TGender read FGender write SetGender;
    property Modified : Boolean read FModified write SetModified;
//    property Picture : TPicture read FPicture write FPicture;
    [JSONMarshalled(False)]
    property Picture : Integer read FPicture write FPicture;
    function Update : Boolean;
    function Delete : Boolean;

    constructor Create(AId : Integer; AFirstName, ALastName : string; AGender : TGender); overload;
    constructor Create(AFirstName, ALastName : string; AGender : TGender); overload;
    destructor destroy; override;

    function ToJsonString: string;

  end;
```

But clearly it has no effect on the marshalling, Picture is still there - what am I missing?

```
function TPerson.ToJsonString: string;
begin
  result := TJson.ObjectToJsonString(self);
end;


08-03-2016 10:26:24 [NORMAL] AddPerson serialized {"firstName":"Donald","lastName":"Duck","id":24,"gender":"Female","modified":false,"picture":92415648}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `TJson.ObjectToJsonString` from `REST.Json` unit and that one needs different attribute to skip fields named `JSONMarshalledAttribute`

You should change your code to `[JSONMarshalledAttribute(False)]`

Delphi has a bit of mix up between older `Data.DBXJsonReflect` and newer `REST.Json` units and you should not mix them together in same code. Pick only one of them.

[REST.Json.TJson.ObjectToJsonString](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/REST.Json.TJson.ObjectToJsonString)

[REST.Json.Types.JSONMarshalledAttribute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/REST.Json.Types.JSONMarshalledAttribute)

[Data.DBXJSONReflect.JSONMarshalled](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Data.DBXJSONReflect.JSONMarshalled)

Comment: Thanks Dalija, yes obviously I had a problem with the mixing now I only have a leak problem which I'll dig into. 
BTW. where on earth do you find those directives like [JSONMarshalledAttribute(False)] ?? and what is the difference between those two?

Comment: You can find list of attributes and other classes and types at [REST.Json.Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/REST.Json.Types) and [Data.DBXJSONReflect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Data.DBXJSONReflect)

Comment: What is the difference - there is none. It is just when new JSON framework was introduced they needed differently named attributes so that backward compatibility would be preserved for people using older code. They could also move that to common units, but it didn't happen at the time.

Comment: It didn't work until I did `using REST.Json.Types` and `[REST.Json.Types.JSONMarshalledAttribute(False)]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I found the solution, when using DBX (and not REST) you'll need add this unit "Data.DBXJSON" rather than the "REST.JSON" and change the two "from/to" methods for un/marshaling the object something like this.

NOTE. ToJSONString leaks for some reason, I'll have to investigate that more.

```
function TPerson.ToJsonString: string;
var
  JSONMarshal: TJSONMarshal;
begin
  result := '';
  JSONMarshal := TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create);
  try
    Result := JSONMarshal.Marshal(self).ToString;
  finally
    JSONMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;

class function TPerson.FromJsonString(AJSONString: string): TPerson;
var
  JSONUnMarshal: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  JSONUnMarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;
  try
    Result := JSONUnMarshal.Unmarshal(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AJSONString)) as TPerson;
  finally
    JSONUnMarshal.Free;
  end;
end;
```